# Stuck/stripped plastic cap - Rock Shox Judy 1

Tags: repair, fork

I'm servicing a [Scott Reflex 40](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/value-guide/product/94142/)- I suspect 2006 model (bought 2nd hand), with [Rock Shox Judy 1 front forks](https://www.servicearchive.sram.com/sites/default/files/techdocs/95.4310.955.000%2006%20Judy%20Service%20Guide%20Rev_A.pdf). I can disassemble the RHS (facing the shocks) but the LHS I am unable to remove the plastic top cap, and in trying to I have stripped it as below:

[image]

Admittedly I'm working with less than fit-for-purpose tools and have removed the RHS with a generic wrench and tried using needle nose pliers for the LHS when it got stuck (to poor results). I'm looking for any advice for removal. I have thought about destroying the cap and buying a replacement but parts are not easy to find (at least where I am currently).

Comment: Have you tried an appropriately-sized hex socket? Modern ones are often designed to apply turning force to the flat sides a bit away from the corners. (example only of corner feature: https://www.homedepot.com/p/TEKTON-1-2-in-Drive-x-1-1-2-in-6-Point-Socket-SHD22038/310620815 )

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the cap is done for.

If you have any penetrating oil (or even GT85/WD40), I'd spray this around the cap. Penetrating oil can degrade plastic over time, but this cap is fairly ruined anyway.

After this, I would carefully drill a small hole in the top of the cap, a couple of millimeters in from the edge, just big enough to put one side of your needle nose pliers in.

Once you have drilled this hole, insert one side of the pliers into the hole (at an angle, with the needle end pointing closer to the anti-clockwise direction), and try and pry the cap round.